# How to write test case for if condition using mocha node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, sinon

I'm trying to write a unit test case for the below code. It's complaining that the line having if doesn't have a unit test covered. I get result from another function.

```
const data = result.map((respBody) => {
  for (let key in respBody._source) {
    if (respBody._source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      //do some stuff here
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: One thing I can do is, I can pull the if block into another function and write a test case for it which solves the problem but looking for some help on how do I write a test case in this case

Comment: If the code inside the `if` isn't covered then the condition isn't true for whatever tests cover it. The way to fix it is to have that condition be true.

Comment: @DaveNewton Can you provide an example for me to write a test for this?

Comment: I have no idea what `respBody` is supposed to be, or what its `_source` property is, etc, so not really. I mean... you can see what the condition is, you can log out multiple points to see what the keys are and whether or not `hasOwnProperty` is returning true/false etc.

Comment: Actually, I don't need the `if` block to explicitly check the key property as the `for` itself gives every key present under _source.